# Data Forwarding to a subsequent lw instruction

Tags: compiler-construction, mips, pipeline, cpu-architecture

Say we have two MIPS instructions one after the other, like so.

i1: add $12, $15, $14

i2: lw $15, 100($12)

After instruction 1 has reached what stage in the MIPS pipeline will i2's lw be able to read from $12? How many times will lw, therefore, end up stalling (how many 'bubbles' does it need)? I'm not sure how far lw can progress without waiting for $12 to be updated.

I'm guessing that i1 will need to reach and complete MEM first, but I am not sure if WB needs to happen before it can load 100($12).

My understanding is the MIPS pipeline goes IF-ID-EX-MEM-WB.

Comment: In the classic MIPS pipeline (exemplified by the R2000), results would be forwarded from the end of the EX stage of one instruction to the beginning of the EX stage of the next instruction. For a load instruction, the result is forwarded from the end of MEM to the beginning of EX (the R2000 had a load delay slot; using the result register of an immediately preceding instruction in the delay slot was illegal and would read the old data unless there was a cache miss). Without forwarding, an R2000-like pipeline would write the register in the first half of WB and read it in the second half of ID.

Comment: Are you saying there would indeed be a stall between i1 and i2? because  i1's MEM lines up with i2's EX. But I didn't think i2 really uses its EX stage since its not an arithmetic instruction (could be dead wrong here). @PaulA.Clayton

Comment: For memory addressing instructions, the EX stage is typically used for address generation (e.g., adding 100 to register 12 in instruction 2). For the example instruction sequence there would be no stalls (assuming standard result forwarding). If i1 had been `lw $12, 8($14)`, then i2 would have to be stalled (loads take two cycles whereas simple ALU instructions take one cycle).